# do serialize bigdecimal affect performance

Tags: java, performance, serialization, bigdecimal

Will serialize and deserialize of BigDecimal affect performance, assuming that I have more than 100 instances in one request.

I am using rest API and I added to the response more than 100 BigDecimal instances. Without the BigDecimal instances, the processing of the response (sending and retrieving) took 10 second less.

Is the time consumer here the BigDecimal serialization?

Comment: You have to profile this a little more. There's not enough info to tell if the issue is the serialization (really this shouldn't take long, but e.g. we have no idea *how* big your numbers are), the network time for transmitting a larger amount of data, or the server just taking longer to do whatever it is it is doing. We can't help you with the info given, you'll have to either narrow it down or provide more information. Try adding some timing calculations and printing out the time each portion of your code (serialize, send, wait for response) takes, that's your simplest next step.

Comment: (Another way to narrow it down is to just temporarily disable portions of your code; for example, construct the request with all your serialized data but don't actually transmit it to the server. If that doesn't take long, then the serialization is not the issue.)

Comment: I agree with Jason, running an example through a profiler will tell you where the time is being used (with GC tracking turned on for good measure).  That said,  readObject on BigDecimal is doing more than just reading data in from the wire.  There is processing and object allocations going on, and depending on how large the numbers are this could take up some time.  If you are close to a GC threshold then you could also be getting pushed into extra unwanted GC too.

Comment: i send the same request on the same environment (network, servers e.g) one time with the instances and one time with out, i did it several times, and i always get the same time difference (without the instances - 10 second less). i also tried in environment with a faster network and still getting the same result. I also compered the size differences between the requests, it was only 20 KB difference.

Comment: i will try to measure the serialization.

Comment: @Itay any update on this issue?  have you run your full test with network traffic through Java Flight Recorder or JProfiler or something similar?     If yes, please attach a summary of the results to the question.

Comment: Serializing `BigDecimal` objects does take *some* time, yes. Whether it's the cause of your issue or not is impossible to tell based on what you've shared. Consider creating an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issues you're seeing.